# How to find the average from a list of numbers in a text file python

Tags: python

Inside the the text file there is a list of name along side a number which denotes their score in this case. is there a way to figure out the average of all the numbers in the text file.

Code:

```
print("average calculator")
option = input("option: ")
option_class = input("class: ")
one = "1.txt"
if option.lower() == 'avg' and option_class == '1':
    name = input("name: ")

    with open(one) as f:
        the_list = [int(l.strip().split()[-1]) for l in f if name in l]

        b = sum(the_list)
        length = len(the_list)
        avg = float(b) / length if length else 0
        print (name,"Average is: ", avg)
```

The section where the code asks the user their name, here it finds all the numbers in the text file that are next to the name, however I am trying to Remove this aspect and allow the code to recognise all the numbers in the file...

Text File:

```
Matt 3
Jhon 4
Alex 6
```

From these numbers, [3,4,6] the average should be worked out, NB: the text file can be appended, more names and scores can be added.

TIA!

Comment: `[int(l.strip().split()[-1]) for l in f if name in l]` change it to `[int(l.strip().split()[-1]) for l in f]`

Comment: And remove this section `name = input("name: ")`

Comment: Thanks! I understand now!

Comment: Just a recommendation, if you are learning don't use code with list comprehension like this `[int(l.strip().split()[-1]) for l in f if name in l]` will be confusing for new python programmers :)

Comment: Sure, but i do kind of grasp the concept!

Comment: You might want to fix your code. Your edit deleted alot of it

Comment: Oh my! How did that happen. wth?!

Comment: @WoodChopper Can you by any chance explain that line of code

Answer (score 0):

try the pandas library.

something of the lines:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', delimiter=' ')
df['Column name'].mean()
```

it has functionality to filter and group data easily, and is much more useful for this kind of task than writing your own code. I working with files 100,000 lines +, and can read, group, filter outliers in each group and compute statistics in about 4 lines of code.

http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: I don't this OP is asking how to do avg. That too using pandas!

Comment: I know it uses pandas. I am suggesting a tool he can use that will make tasks like this much simpler. Do you really believe it is better to implement functionality like grouping yourself than use an already implemented and efficient library. Writing your own code means it is far less general, and given the aims, an out of the box solution makes more sense.

Comment: yes, but equally I am suggesting a better, quicker and more robust method. How is that not a useful answer?

Comment: fyi, I didn't down vote your answer, some one else agree with me.

Comment: @Chris I had researched the csv methods however in my context the answer from WoodChopper was the one i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension:

```
the_list = [int(l.strip().split()[-1]) for l in f if name in l]
```

Equivalent:

```
with open(one) as f:
    the_list = []   # creating empty list or (array)
    for l in f:     # treversing over the lines in file
        if name in l:  # if input name is in the line do next line
            the_list.append(int(l.strip().split()[-1])) # adding element to list
        else:   # if input name is not in line ignore the line dont use the score
            pass
```